# Auto refresh Tableau online dashboard using "Auto refresh" Chrome extension

Tags: refresh, tableau-api

I've created a view in tableau online using a live connection. I want to the page to refresh automaticly every 10 minutes. It can only be done by pressing manually the refresh button in the dashboard/view in tableau online, refreshing the browser page wont refresh the dashboard. I saw a tableau discussion with this tip: `"Tip: To continually refresh a view, in the <head> section of the web page, add <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#">, where # is the number of seconds between refreshes."` How can I do this? Can this be done in tableau online?

As a second option I can add parameters to the dashboard URL to fix this issue. I saw this in this discussion: https://community.tableau.com/thread/289924 At least the part `":refresh=yes"` had to be added to the URL. Since I'm totally unknown in this area I was not able to fix this. Where and how I need to add this to the url so this will permantly works?

I'm also open for other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could approach this, which one you choose will depend on your situation, scale, and available resources.

### Option 1: Embed with meta tag

This is the first option you were describing. In order to do this, you will need to embed your dashboard into your own custom separate webpage. You can get the embed code from the [share button](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed.htm) on any dashboard and can customize it using parameters and the [JavaScript Embedding API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm). The meta tag you mentioned would then go in the header of your custom webpage where you are embedding the dashboard. So it would look something like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Your embed code from the dashboard here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You would also want to make sure to include the `:refresh` tag you mentioned so you always get the latest data.

**Pros**: Anyone can open the page and have an auto-refreshing dashboard without installing anything.

**Cons**: You will need to have some form of a webserver to host your custom page. Requires some coding. Hard to scale up the number of dashboards.

### Option 2: Chrome Extension

This is the second option you were describing. In this case, a chrome extension in the browser is refreshing the page for you. That means you don't need your own separate webpage. However, it will only work on the browser you install and setup the extension on. It looks like there are a couple of auto-refresh extensions in the [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Auto%20Refresh) you can choose from. You would need to configure them to refresh the page, again make sure to include the `:refresh` tag on the url.

**Pros**: Don't need a separate webserver. No coding. Easy to scale for multiple dashboards.

**Cons**: Only works for the browser that the chrome extension is installed on.

### Option 3: Dashboard extension

One option you didn't mention but I think is the best would be to use a [Dashboard Extension](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboard_extensions.htm). Dashboard extensions are web apps that you can bring directly into the dashboard. We currently have an [Auto-Refresh](https://extensiongallery.tableau.com/products/115?version=2019.4) extension in the gallery built for just this purpose. Once you've downloaded it simply open your dashboard, drag in a new extension object, select the downloaded file and configure for 10 minutes.

**Pros**: Don't need a separate webserver. No coding. Easy to scale for multiple dashboards. Anyone can open the dashboard and have it auto-refreshing without installing anything.

**Cons**: Auto-Refresh only works with 2019.4+.

Hope this helps!

Comment: does this work with Live connections as well?

Comment: Hi @Ade_1, this would only work with live connections. Extracts cannot be refreshed with these methods.