# Auto update data source in Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to automatically update a .txt file-based data source in Tableau Desktop but can't find how to do it. What I want is to see a "live" chart on a worksheet not having to push F5 every time. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's not.
Tableau Desktop is the editor you can use to create visualizations and it's not build to shove "live" data even though you can refresh data via F5.

You can achieve something like you want, publishing your dashboard to a Tableau Server/Online and then using some tricks.

Please check this related S.O. post:
[Auto refresh Tableau online dashboard using "Auto refresh" Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59613817/auto-refresh-tableau-online-dashboard-using-auto-refresh-chrome-extension)